# Precisely speaking, does photon become massive or the phonon become massive, due to Higgs mechanism in superconductor?

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, superconductivity, superfluidity

Consider the low-energy field theories of superfluids and superconductors.

In superfluids, the spontaneous breaking of the order parameter's phase creates phonons as the massless Goldstone bosons.(**Is it true? Or the massless excitation is the second sound rather than phonons.**)

In superconductors, the spontaneous breaking of the charged order parameter's phase doesn't lead to a massless Goldstone boson. Due to the Higgs mechanism, it creates a massive Higgs mode instead.

**Why saying the photons in a superconductor become massive due to the Higgs mechanism, instead of saying that the phonons, which ought to be created if the field is not charged, become massive due to Higss mechanism**

Comment: What is broken in a superfluid is the translation operation, so the Goldstone mode is in fact associated with the phonon, as usual when dealing with translation symmetry breaking. In a superconductor, what is broken is the Abelian gauge-redundancy. Usually the associated boson with this gauge-field is the photon, that's why one says "photon becomes massive" when one considers superconductivity.

Comment: Superfluid spontaneously breaks $U(1)$ particle number conservation, and has nothing to do with the spatial translation symmetry. The Goldstone mode is called phonon because it is related to density fluctuations, but should not be confused with phonons in a crystal resulting from translation symmetry breaking.

Comment: In a superconductor the global $U(1)$ symmetry is promoted to a gauge symmetry, and gauge symmetry can not be broken. The phase of the charged order parameter is not a well-defined physical quantity precisely because of the $U(1)$ gauge symmetry. Therefore people often work in a gauge where the phase of the order parameter is set to $0$, so the action of the Abelian gauge field $A$ becomes $\text{Maxwell term}+\rho A^2$, which has a gapped spectrum.

Comment: @MengCheng In your first comment, what do you mean by break $U(1)$ particle number conservation, is it the same to my statement that the spontanously breaks the phase of the order parameter?(Or you mean in the thermodynamic limit, the groud state of different number of particles degenerate, the real physical state choose one of them, thus break the particle number conservation) Also, how does the corresponding goldstone mode related to density fluctuations if it is not some kind of sound?

Comment: @MengCheng In your comment of superconductivity, do you mean that there is no physical symmetry broken? However, considering the Josephson effect, it implies that different superconductors may have different phase, which seems to me that the degenerate groud states are caracterized by the phase of the superconductor.